# Firebase Authentication: firebase.isLoggedIn gives Two values false and True Despite Being Logged In

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

After Logging up in my website. I checked the firebase.isLoggedIn value in my case it should only print true but on console it prints first false and true                                              here is the firebase.jsx file

```
import { createContext ,useContext ,useState ,useEffect} from "react";
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, 
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword , 
    sendEmailVerification ,
    onAuthStateChanged,
    signOut,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword} 
    from 'firebase/auth';
import firebaseConfig from "./Api";
import Password from "antd/es/input/Password";


const FirebaseContext = createContext(null);


export const useFirebase = () =\> useContext(FirebaseContext);

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firebaseAuth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

export const FirebaseProvider = (props) =\> {

    const \[user ,setUser\] = useState(null);


    useEffect(() =\>{
        onAuthStateChanged(firebaseAuth ,user =\>{
           
            if(user) setUser(user)
            else setUser(null);
        })
    })

    const SignupUserWithEmailAndPass = async (email, password) =\> { // Changed parameter names
        try {
          const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(firebaseAuth, email, password);
          // Send email verification
          await sendEmailVerification(userCredential.user); // Changed this line
        } catch (error) {
          // Handle any errors here
          console.error("Error creating user:", error);
        }
      };

      const signInUserWithEmailAndPass = (email , password) =\> signInWithEmailAndPassword(firebaseAuth,email,password);

      const isLoggedIn = user ? true : false;

      const SignOut = () =\> {
        return signOut(firebaseAuth);
      };

    return \<FirebaseContext.Provider 
    value={{SignupUserWithEmailAndPass ,
            signInUserWithEmailAndPass,
            SignOut,
            isLoggedIn}}\>
        {props.children}
        \</FirebaseContext.Provider\>
};
```

and the page where i am logging the value: Query.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useFirebase } from "../context/Firebase";

function Query(){
  const firebase = useFirebase();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

console.log(firebase.isLoggedIn);

    return <h1 style={{paddingTop:"10vh"}}>welcome to query resolver</h1>
}

export default Query;
```

when i  am logged out it shows only one value false which is right but the problem occurs when i am logged in . And firebaseConfig contains all the keys no errors in that